# Building Android from Source -File not found error

Tags: java, android, android-source

I've been following the build tutorials on source.android.com in attempt to build ICS.  When I use the make command, I'm getting a File not found error.

Does anybody have more experience with this?

Here is the console, starting with my make command:

```
[root@dev working_directory]# make
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=AOSP
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.0.3.0.2.0.1.0
TARGET_PRODUCT=full
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=OPENMASTER
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
/bin/bash: line 0: cd: cts/tools/cts-native-xml-generator/src/res: No such file or directory
host C: acp <= build/tools/acp/acp.c
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:387:0,
             from /usr/include/stdlib.h:25,
             from build/tools/acp/acp.c:11:
/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:7:27: fatal error: gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/acp_intermediates/acp.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems you have some packages missing. Follow the instructions available at http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html to set up your environment.

Comment: thanks our ended up being a couple of packages that are needed for fedora

Comment: i also facing same problem, do u have any solution.